# How to paste an item selected by external FZF in the cursor position?

Tags: external-command, shell, fzf

I know I can paste output of external shell command with `:read! ls`.

But `:read! ls|fzf` doesn't work for me.

Is there a way for me to go from vim to shell, use fzf to select an item, then go back to vim to paste it in current cursor position?

Comment: Why don't you use the FZF Vim plugin?

Comment: @romainl For most of use cases of FZF plugin, I use vim's built in functionality instead. I like to get away with not installing FZF.vim if there is an easier solution.

Comment: Well, other than `SIGTERM` and friends, there is no IPC to speak of between the shell and Vim so you are basically left with… the system clipboard.

Comment: @romainl too bad. I guess, I have to use fzf.vim after all.  thanx anyway.

Comment: Er, it's `:read !ls`. I'm able to use pipes like `:read !ls | grep foo`, so it must be FZF that's broken :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for correcting me. `:read !ls | grep foo` works for me as well but not FZF. I think it is because grep doesn't need any additional user interaction, so output form the shell just piped in to the vim buffer. While FZF requires input from users to fuzzy find form the list and `read` mechanism doesn't have a way to open a full functional shell to take user inupt.